# Outlook 365 does it have IMAP Idle feature which receives emails immediately, if so, how to activate it?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-365

I think it's called [`IMAP Idle`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP_IDLE) feature, I know Thunderbird out of box have this feature, where all my accounts receive emails immediately, but in Outlook 365 it seems it only receives new emails on scheduled fetch which is minimum 1 minute or when I manually  hit send/receive button.

Comment: Evidently this question didn't meet criteria for an answer and because of that it was downvoted:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipopw.png

Comment: @John If you'd think your answer was helpful, you'd leave it, but you deleted it and in revenge downvoted the question. "the answer works, but the question is wrong and should be deleted" brilliant, lol

Comment: John, `IMAP Idle` is when client can receive new messages as soon as they arrived at the server, theoretically it can receive them every second and without any user interaction. On fresh Outlook 365 install this feature either disabled by default or not present at all. By default, Outlook checks for new emails on schedule every 10 minutes, which can be lowered down to 1 minute. So, if you claim that `IMAP idle` is present, how does one activate it? - that is the question, and not "how to check new emails on demand"

Comment: Ok, now I'm convinced you either a troll, or there is something wrong with you...how is pushing a button related to "without user interaction"?

Comment: I'm not obligated do anything; however, you seem to think you obligated answer every question, regardless how little you know. Ever heard expression "Throwing sh!t at the wall to see what sticks"? - that's what some of your answers are.